# Wire bearings on actuators on military ships

Tags: bearings, naval-engineering

While reading about the *Korvette K130 Braunschweig* class of corvettes for the German navy, I noticed that almost all of the weapon systems are held in what I'd call a *wire bearing*.
I'd like to know what its actual designation and its purpose are.

Examples:

- [MASS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MASS_(T%C3%A4uschk%C3%B6rperwerfer)#/media/Datei:Pori_MASS_decoy.JPG)
- [RBS 15](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korvette_K130#/media/Datei:RBS_15_Mk3_-_Seezielflugk%C3%B6rper_-_Abschussrampe_(6059656292).jpg)
- [RAM](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korvette_K130#/media/Datei:Korvette_Magdeburg_F261_(6059116043).jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called “wire rope dampers” or “wire rope isolaters”, and their purpose is to increase the time over which recoil energy is transferred into the mounting, thus reducing the peak force.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine they act primarily as shock absorbers to handle the recoil.